# Winforms Control Validation Order

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a winforms app that from a very high level displays a bunch of financial data in a datagridview where each column represents a week number of the year.  The program gives the ability to right click a cell and copy its value to a range of cells in the grid.

Right clicking the source cell opens up a simple Form where the user can enter a start week and a stop week.  Once the start/stop week inputs are validated, the parent form retrieves the values and uses them to copy the source value to the range of target cells.

The final validation check in my "Stop Week" validating event handler compares the start week value to the stop week value to make sure that the start week is less than the stop week.  In order for this to work, I need the "Start Week" validating event to fire before the "Stop Week" validating event.  As additional information, I am triggering validation with the following block of code

```
    Private Sub HandleOkButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If ValidateChildren(ValidationConstraints.Enabled) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Validation Passes")
            DialogResult = DialogResult.OK
            Close()
        Else 
            MessageBox.Show("Validation Fails")
        End If
    End Sub
```

When I first started working on this code however, the "Stop Week" validating event was firing first.  What I found was that in the designer file, the "Stop Week" textbox was added to the forms control collection before the "Start Week" textbox.  The only way I have been able to control the sequence of validating events is to change the order that controls are added to the Forms Controls collection in the designer.  This seems like a sub optimal solution.

Is there a better way to control the sequence in which form controls validate?

Comment: `Is there a better way to control the sequence in which form controls validate`, sure there is, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Override `ValidateChildren` and implement your custom logic.

Comment: It simply iterates the child controls in the order in which they are stored in the Controls collection.  The "natural" order, front to back.  The last control you added is in front, on top of any it might overlap.  Using View > Other Windows > Document Outline is the easiest way to see that order and to easily change it by dragging.  Do note that this is different from navigation order, that's set by the TabIndex property.

Comment: @HansPassant Good point with the TabIndex.  I tried playing around with those values to see if it affected validation order and found that it did not.  If you put your response about how it iterates the child controls in the order they are added, I will mark it as the accepted answer

Comment: @RezaAghaei I up voted your comment since it is indeed a valid approach that would work.  I was hoping a solution that would work "out of the box" so to speak without overriding .Net default functionality, but I did not specify that in the question, so your answer is definitely valid.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I am always interested in learning better ways to do things.  I would definitely be interested in your ideas even if they are based on opinions

Comment: @HansPassant There it is again! The Document Outline. Saved me when I was trying to deal with Panels. (Your comment several years ago.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValidateChildren` [internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,d7b32bf2c7dcc0d0) uses a loop over `Controls` collection and validate the child controls in the same order which they appear in `Controls` collection.

To change the order of raising `Validating` event, you can use either of the following options:

- At design-time, use *Document Outline* window to reorder the controls
- At run-time, change the control index in the controls collection using [`Controls.SetChildIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)
- Override [`ValidateChildren`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.validatechildren?view=netframework-4.7.2) and implement your custom logic to raise the `Validating` events in a custom order (for example based on the `TabOrder`).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set TabIndex in Properties window

```vb
For Each ctrl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Control).OrderBy(Function(c) c.TabIndex)
  Debug.Print(ctrl.Name)
Next
```

Reorders for the duration of the For...Next

2. You can also edit the order in Form1.Designer.vb where the controls are added to Controls collection. Risky business, I believe it gets overwritten at certain times.

Comment: It doesn't raise the `Validating` event based on `TabIndex`. In fact it raises the event for controls in the same order which they appear in Controls collection.